# Invalid operands of types 'char' and 'char*' to binary 'operator*'?

Tags: c++

Hice esta funcion en c++ para invertir una palabra

```
void cambio(char*); //cadena a ingresar
void cambio(char *v){
int d=strlen(v); //dimensión de la cadena
int e= d-1; // valor para leer la cadena desde el último carácter
char temp; // variable temporal
for(int i=0; i<(d/2); i++){
    temp= *(v+i)
    *(v+i) = *(v+(e+i)); //el error me lo produce en esta línea
    *(v+(e+i))=temp; 

}
return;
}
```

ayuda :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se te olvida el punto y coma:

```
void cambio(char *v){
int d=strlen(v); //dimensión de la cadena
int e= d-1; // valor para leer la cadena desde el último carácter
char temp; // variable temporal
for(int i=0; i<(d/2); i++){
    temp= *(v+i); // <= Aquí
    *(v+i) = *(v+(e+i)); //el error me lo produce en esta línea
    *(v+(e+i))=temp; 

}
return;
}
```

De todas formas, aparte de no ser necesario declarar la función si justo después la defines, no necesitas tratar con aritmética de punteros constantemente, puedes utilizar el operador `[]`:

```
void cambio(char *v) {

    int d = strlen(v);
    char temp; // variable temporal

    for(int i = 0; i < (d / 2); ++i) { // ++i mejor que i++
        temp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[d + i - 1];
        v[d + i - 1] = temp;
    }

    // return; // No necesitas poner `return` en una funcion `void`.
}
```